# Query caching when user goes back

Tags: php, mysql, caching, cookies

I have a page that queries a MySql database and then displays the results as HTML. Assuming the database changes, will the new changes to the database be reflected when a user goes BACK to the page?
I am worried that the data the user got when they first went to the page hasn't changes when they go back. Is there a way to prevent data from being cached when a user goes to the page.

Comment: not only the database but chrome back button (i.e. at least chrome) has a special feature that gives you the cache of even the *last ajax request*, so you probably don't even have a hand on it unless you disable that option (I ignore whether this is even possible)

Answer (score 0):

If your page doesn't specify the caching behavior, then the browser will take its best guess at whether it should cache the page or not. In some cases when a user hits 'back', the browser will show the same page, in other cases it might not.

You should explicitly tell the browser not to cache the page and to re-validate it. You can use the code below to achieve this:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```